# SQL - Not existing rows as existing

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. One with a list of users, one with items and one with relation between the users and the items. User can have an item (stat = 0/1) or can have a duplicate (dup = 0/1). If you click on the item's or the duplicate's button, it runs a query that adds or updates the row.

It looks like this:

| user | item_id | stat | dup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 4 | 1 | 0 |

I compare these data who have an item what the other does not have and vica versa with this query:

```
SELECT t2.user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.dup=1 AND t2.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `My Item List`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.dup=1 AND t1.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `Item List`
FROM table3 t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2 USING (item_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = @current_user
  AND t2.user_id <> @current_user
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

My problem is I can only compare the rows if the user has already clicked the buttons at least once, so the row generated, but I need the stat=0 and dup=0 rows as well even if they are not existing.

How can I integrate this to the query above?

My tables:

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_group varchar(255)
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not an expert in MySQL, so I can only show you the idea:

Such task is usually done with a subquery which creates a list of primary keys, and use that subquery as a primary in the from, other tables are added as outer joins:

```
SELECT pks.user_id, pks.item_id, t.stat, t.dup
FROM (select t1.id as user_id, t2.item_id from table1 t1, table2 t2) pks
OUTER JOIN table3 t on pks.user_id = t.user_id and pks.item_id = t.item_id
```

Here, third and fourth columns would have 0/1 if the `table3` already has a record for the user/item pair and NULLs for cases without a corresponding record in `table3`.